# Apache Camel integration with Activiti6 beta4

Tags: spring, apache-camel, activiti

I'm trying to use Camel with Activiti6 beta4 using only the UI (activiti-app).
But in the log of the execution of my process model I get the error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'myContext' is defined
```

It seems that the UI is unable to find my applicationContext.xml and/or "myContext" (the camel context inside applicationContext.xml).
My applicationContext.xml is in the /WEB-INF and has this content:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">

    <camelContext id="myContext" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <route>
        :::::::MY ROUTE::::::
        </route>
    </camelContext>
</beans>
```

Would anyone tell me what is missing?
The name and location of "applicationContext.xml" are correct?

TIA,
Wanderlan

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to using Activiti 6 beta with Camel, but I have it working on th 5.x engine and Activiti Enterprise Edition (with some hacking).

The default Camel Context that is installed is called camelContext, I see you have declared a Camel context called myContext. For some reason that bean has not instantiated or cannot be found.

Try using he default id of camelContext and see if your behavior changes.

Greg

Comment: Thank you Greg. But no effect. The message is the same, only changed the bean name to "camelContext"  
`Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'camelContext' is defined`

The behavior is the same on Activiti Enterprise Edition v. 1.5 and on Activiti 5.21 Free Edition. 

The name of "\WEB-INF\applicationContext.xml" seems to be the key issue. I try others names: application-context.xml, application-standalone-context.xml, etc and nothing...

Comment: I can guarantee that Camel integration in Enterprise edition will not work. The behavior classes are missing. A defect has been entered and I'm told it will be fixed soon. As for Community Edition 5.21, as long as you compile the war with the camel module included, the default context should load. Make sure you have the component scanner setup properly to pick up the bean.

Comment: I decided to continue with Activiti6, but taking another direction, instead of using Spring DSL to specify my routes in Camel, I decided to use Groovy in Script Tasks. This approach is more flexible, agile and powerful (at least for me), also I do not need an IDE like Eclipse. Just I changed my Camel Tasks to Script Tasks and put the following Groovy script:
`import org.apache.camel.*
import org.apache.camel.impl.*
import org.apache.camel.builder.*
def myContext=new DefaultCamelContext()
myContext.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder(){def void configure(){/*MY ROUTE*/}})
myContext.start()`